# Find string between brackets

Tags: c#

I'm having a string that could look like this:

```
{
    "acl_gent": {
        "cluster": [],
        "indices": [{
            "names": ["am*"],
            "privileges": ["read", "view_index_metadata"],
            "query": "{\"match\": {\"ACL\": \"acl_gent\"}}"
        }],
        "run_as": []
    },
    "acl_luik": {
        "cluster": [],
        "indices": [{
            "names": ["am*"],
            "privileges": ["read", "view_index_metadata"],
            "query": "{\"match\": {\"ACL\": \"acl_luik\"}}"
        }],
        "run_as": []
    }
}
```

and I would like to split it up in to 2 strings, 1 containing the **acl_gent** and one conaining **acl_luik**

the string above can contain more then 2 acl's (and I **DON'T** know what the name will be)

so I started removing the first and last bracketes :

`input = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2);`

but then I can't figure out on how to find the right closing bracket to extract the data.

this was the closest I got

```
private int closer(string input) {
    var i = input.IndexOf('}');
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[DEBUG] Checking: {0}", input.Substring(0, i).Contains('{')));
    if (input.Substring(0, i).Contains('{')) {
        return i + closer(input.Substring(i)) + 2;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: How about you parse it properly? (I mean, using a JSON parser)

Comment: This is JSON and should be treated like that using c#'s build-in features for JSON arrays.

Comment: This type of notation is called JSON. I think your keyword is it. Search on google with this query: `How can I parse JSON string in C#`. I think you'll find your answer there.

Comment: look at this library : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: It may look like JSON, but it isn't in the real scenario, and I'm  not asking to parse it, I'm asking to split. Read before you downvote please!

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a JSON string, a common response from a web service, and there are plenty of libraries to parse JSON, the most common one being [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). With this you could do something like

`JObject myJsonObject = JObject.Parse(myResponse)`

and retrieve your strings by their key names, such as

`JObject aclString = myJsonObject["acl_luik"];`

There are plenty of resources online for parsing JSON strings if you wish to go into more detail.

Comment: Can't parse the data

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1) Parse as JSON and get the first 2 objects, this is the better one.

2) Parse using Stack as string of tokens to get what you want, like this:
 - Remove the first and last { }
 - Using stack, add all { you find, and once you find } remove the first { in the stack.
 - Once the stack is empty then you get 1 complete object there, save the indeces while you work and it should be easy to substring with start and end.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently. My solution was to deserialize the string to a json object (in my case a JObject using [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) and then accessing the individual members and serializing them to separate strings.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public void MakeStrings(string json)
{
    var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
    string acl_gent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobject["acl_gent"]);
    string acl_luik = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobject["acl_luik"]);
}
```

Comment: OK, it works for me. Make sure the string has proper escape sequences before you use it as input.

Comment: Indeed, was my bad :p